# Has trinidad 2.0 been superseded or obsoleted?

Tags: java, jsf, trinidad

I'm currently trying to find resources to help me learn Trinidad 2.0 for a project I'm employed on. I'm having trouble finding resources for 2.0 even though there are quite a few resources for 1.2.

Usually this is a sign that a technology has fallen out of favour and there are better options to pursue. Is Trinidad just marking time or is it a good idea to be pursuing it? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trinidad 2 is still active. A lot of the docs are for 1.2 or 2.0 with jsp but once you get past that it isn't too hard to figure out how to use it. I think it is tested a little better with MyFaces but it'll work with Mojarra. Trinidad gets used a lot with ADF/JDeveloper so if you are ever going to get into that then you should learn the Trinidad components. Some of the ADF docs cover aspects about Trnidad like the skinning support.

Other component libraries would be RichFaces, ICEFaces, and PrimeFaces.